Are all solutions to a HORN-SAT problem required to contain the minimal model as a subset?
I'm studying HORN-SAT problems and I have a specific question about the minimal model.
Given a HORN-SAT problem with multiple solutions, I understand that the minimal model is the one with the smallest number of variables set to true.
For example, in a HORN-SAT problem with five variables (A, B, C, D, E), suppose the minimal model is found to be A=1 and C=1, leaving B, D, and E as free variables that can take either 0 or 1.
Is it required that any solution to the problem has A=1 and C=1, as dictated by the minimal model?
My question is: Must all solutions to the HORN-SAT problem contain the minimal model as a subset? In other words, if the minimal model requires certain variables to be 1, then these variables must be 1 in all satisfying solutions ?
I'd appreciate any references or explanations to understand this better.

Yes.  The minimal model is unique.  Moreover, if $M$ is the minimal model (i.e., out of all satisfying assignments, it has the fewest set of variable set to true), and if $S$ is any model, then every variable set to true by $M$ is also set to true by $S$ (i.e., $M$ implies $S$).
One helpful fact is that if $S,T$ are two models (satisfying assignments), then their logical conjunction $S \land T$ is also a valid model (satisfying assignment).  (Here the logical conjunction sets a variable to true iff both $S$ and $T$ set that variable to true.)  The proof of this fact is listed below.
Now if we let $S_1,\dots,S_n$ be all valid models (all satisfying assignments), then $M := S_1 \land \dots \land S_T$ will by the above fact also be a valid model, and it will be the minimal satisfying assignment.  It is also possible to see that $M$ implies every $S_i$ (i.e., is a "subset"), since $S_i \land (\text{anything})$ automatically implies $S_i$.

Proof of the above fact:
This can be proven by looking at any individual Horn clause, say $(x_1 \land \dots \land x_k) \implies y$, and checking that if $S,T$ satisfy it, then $S \land T$ does too.  Specifically, assume $(S[x_1] \land \dots \land S[x_k]) \implies S[y]$ and $(T[x_1] \land \dots \land T[x_k]) \implies T[y]$ are both true.  Then there are two cases:

Case 1: $S[y]$ is false.  Then by our assumption, $(S[x_1] \land \dots \land S[x_k])$ must be false, so there must be some $i$ such that $S[x_i]$ is false.  It follows that $(S \land T)[x_i]$ is false, so $((S\land T)[x_1] \land \dots \land (S\land T)[x_k])$ is false, so $S \land T$ automatically satisfies the clause $(x_1 \land \dots \land x_k) \implies y$.

Case 2: $T[y]$ is false.  The reasoning is symmetrical to Case 1.

Case 3: $S[y]$ and $T[y]$ are both true.  Then $(S \land T)[y]$ is true, so $S \land T$ automatically satisfies the clause $(x_1 \land \dots \land x_k) \implies y$.


It follows that if $S,T$ are valid models (they satisfy all clauses), then $S \land T$ is a valid model (it too satisfies all clauses).
